# run system() command from R script

Tags: r, system

I have R, R Studio and R-tools installed on Windows 7.

I am trying to: cd into a directory and execute a command, this is what I am getting from R, it returns M, what does that mean ?

```
> system(paste("cmd.exe", input = "cd c:/Users/X123/Desktop/FASTLOAD/", "&& fastload < load_journey.fl > output.txt", sep=" "))
M
>
```

what am I doing wrong ?  I never see the command executed, thanks!

---

I changed it from system() to shell() and it works now, but get a bunch of warning messages, is that ok or should I do something for them to go away ?

```
> shell(paste("cd c:/Users/X123/Desktop/FASTLOAD/ ", "&& fastload < load_journey.fl > output.txt", sep=" "))
Warning messages:
1: running command 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c cd c:/Users/X123/Desktop/FASTLOAD/  && fastload < load_journey.fl > output.txt' had status 4 
2: In shell(paste("cd c:/Users/X123/Desktop/FASTLOAD/ ", "&& fastload < load_journey.fl > output.txt",  :
  'cd c:/Users/X123/Desktop/FASTLOAD/  && fastload < load_journey.fl > output.txt' execution failed with error code 4
>
```

Comment: What is the exact output you get if you run this command manually in a terminal?

Comment: I changed the system() to shell() it works now, but get warning messages, is it because I have the slashes backwards or not getting it ?

Comment: when I run at the terminal, nothing is displayed, it runs and then when it finishes, it returns to the command prompt and the output.txt file is created.

Comment: Error 4 typically means "file not found", which could refer to `fastload`, `load_journey.fl`, or `output.txt` (not likely to be this one). Are you certain `fastload` is in the path? If `Sys.which("fastload")` doesn't tell you where `fastload` is located, then your shell command won't work either.

Comment: I think it is in the $PATH / because this:  > Sys.which("fastload")
                                                  fastload 
"C:\\PROGRA~2\\Teradata\\Client\\15.10\\bin\\fastload.exe" 
>

Comment: Also it works, it gives me those warning messages, but it works... the output.txt is created by fastload (if it is not there), that's fastload's job to create it.

Comment: So the weird part is that it definitely works, but it gives me those warning messages anyways, which is weird...

Comment: `system("cmd.exe", input = paste("cd c:/Users/X123/Desktop/FASTLOAD/", "&& fastload < load_journey.fl > output.txt"))` executed for me. Move the paste to your input argument.

Comment: thanks, I will try it when I get to work today and close the Question if it works :-) thanks a lot again for your input and help!

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks!